# Is there an easy way to setup the android emulator to access the LAN of the host machine?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I would like to access a web service provided by one of the machines on my LAN from the android emulator.

If the service was running on the same machine where the emulator is running (called host), I could add a network redirection and access the 10.0.2.2 (host loopback interface in the emulator) with the correct port.

However it is running on another machine on the LAN. I guess I could add another redirection on the host additionally to the above one (would have to fight with iptables though ... ), but does a more simple solution exist ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it just works (TM).

In the android emulator manual that I had read before testing (I try to RTFM before doing things) this is stated:

> Each instance of the emulator runs behind a virtual router/firewall service that isolates it from your development machine's network interfaces and settings and from the internet. An emulated device can not see your development machine or other emulator instances on the network. Instead, it sees only that it is connected through Ethernet to a router/firewall.

This made me think that it could not access my LAN. I was wrong, just adding the IP of the server on my LAN allowed me to access it from the emulator.

Comment: @Dediqated: I think Longfield simply means that you can target machines on the LAN by their normal IP address from the emulator. However, in practice there are limitations, stated [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkinglimitations); notably: firewalls (program on host or device that the host is connected to) may interfere, IGMP and multicast are currently not supported.

Comment: Can I choose to connect to a different wifi LAN?

Answer (score 4):

As we know, emulator can access host machine by IP 10.0.2.2, so I tried IP forwarding but I could not make it working.. :|

I followed link below for forwarding request from localhost(10.0.2.2 in case of emulator) to the other machine in LAN.

http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-redirecting-network-traffic-a-new-ip-using-iptables

Answer (score 2):

as of **2018-08** it seems the "it just works (TM)" certificate has been revoked

here is what I needed to access a server in my local network:

```
host ip (my pc): 192.168.15.102/24 
      server ip: 192.168.200.33/24
```

create a port forwarding rule in an elevated command prompt on **host** using `netsh`

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=80 connectport=80 connectaddress=192.168.200.33
```

start the mobile device emulator and browse to **10.0.2.2** 
(as mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking#networkaddresses)):

> 10.0.2.2
>   Special alias to your host loopback interface (i.e., 127.0.0.1 on your development machine)

Answer (score -2):

You could get an actual android device and connect it to the LAN (i have done this).

How are you connecting to the host machine? through html? because if your app requires a hard line connection to the machine then its not a very good solution for a *mobile* device.

Comment: if its html i dont see a problem.

Comment: Yeah I have already tested this with my android device and it works. However it would be nice to be able to do it with the emulator as well.

What do you mean by hard line ? It's not html, but a client commands interface on TCP, so quite similar.