# Failed connecting socket to local server

Tags: android, android-networking

Although I set ip address to 10.0.2.2 as recommended, the instruction

```
Socket s = new Socket("10.0.2.2",8080);
```

still gives me

```
08-24 08:02:54.404: W/System.err(1030): failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 8080): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

I'm sure server works because I tried it with another client program, so emulator has something wrong...can you help me?
edit: android.permission.internet is set too!

Comment: What about if you giving System's static IP???

Comment: Have you enabled the necessary permissions?

Answer (score 1):

A similiar question has been asked at:
[setup the android emulator to access the LAN of the host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010130/is-there-an-easy-way-to-setup-the-android-emulator-to-access-the-lan-of-the-host)

See what you can find there.

Answer (score 0):

Check is any firewall is running and some antivirus act as firewall so stop the antivirus and try again

Answer (score -2):

Solved...it was just a bug in the code, it had nothing to do with the main procedure...sorry!