# Make Android emulator have an IP of host machine LAN

Tags: android, networking, android-emulator

I got a follow up question to this question:

[Is there an easy way to setup the android emulator to access the LAN of the host machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010130/is-there-an-easy-way-to-setup-the-android-emulator-to-access-the-lan-of-the-host)

I have read the answers to the question above but did not understand what I should do And how to config the IP.

I am running an Emulator which is supposed to connect to a server on the hosting station's (personal computer which I ran the emulator on) LAN with other emulators and they should connect with each other through the server.

The emulators have no problem connecting to the server, but they each do it with the address of 10.0.2.15 so the responds from the server are sent to that address instead to my local machine and from there to the emulator.

I read here:
http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking

That I should config a static address of 10.0.2.2 but I'm not sure how. I read a guide that said I should go to settings -> Wireless & networks -> Wifi and there change the IP, but my Wireless & networks menu don't have a "Wifi" option at all.

So how can I config the IP of the emulator to be the same as the working station's IP?

Comment: That is impossible as the emulator is a different device and different devices cannot have the same ip in the same LAN.

Comment: 10.0.2.2 isn't an address you would configure. It's given.