# WCF used in Android Project (FileNotFoundException)

Tags: java, c#, android, json, wcf

I have a simple web service in c#.
Here is the C# code :

IService1.cs

```
[ServiceContract(ConfigurationName = "IService")]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet]
        string TestAndroid();
    }
```

Service1.svc.cs

```
public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string TestAndroid()
        {
            return "Test done !";
        }
    }
```

Here is the Android code :

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {

        try {

            URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:49363/Service1.svc/TestAndroid");

            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

            String line = reader.readLine();

            reader.close();

        } catch(Exception e){
            return false;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

When I want to read the InputStream, I have an error.

It's

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   http://10.0.2.2:49363/Service1.svc/TestAndroid

I don't know where is the problem, because when I go in browser I have

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">Test done !</string>
```

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope your service is working and you had tested it on your computer by invoking url http://10.0.2.2:49363/Service1.svc/TestAndroid
Am I right?

Then simple explanation for your issue would be that your Android doesn't know about ip address 10.0.2.2.

Can you validate that is accessible? Just try to open the same url in browser on your Android device.

Simple solution to see this IP  address - your phone should be on the same WiFi as your computer.

Update: 
Goal is to see computer with service running WCF host. Question is - can Android device see WCF host?

The opposite direction is irrelevant but it's good to know that 
Android emulator cannot be seen from the computer. Here is good [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010130/is-there-an-easy-way-to-setup-the-android-emulator-to-access-the-lan-of-the-host)

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping me.
I tried http://10.0.2.2/ in my android virtual device and I can't reach. I have 'Connection problem

 net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT'

Comment: That explains why you have this exception. You should concentrate on issue that your android phone has no connection you your computer with service. As I said - put them on one WiFi or make sure that your 10.0.2.2 is global address (which I doubt) and accessible for everybody (inducing me)

Comment: The IP address of my android emulator is 10.0.2.15 but when I do http://10.0.2.15, I have 'net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED'. 
How can I access to the localhost if it's not this adress ?

Comment: So I can't test the webservice with my android emulator ? I have an android phone but I think I can't call my web service because the phone doesn't know 'localhost'. Can you please help me by telling how can I test my WCF in my android project ? @alex

Comment: Use real local address. Use IPCONFIG to find it. It will be something like 192.168,,,, Address like 10.0.2.2 or 10.0.2.3 or "hardcoded" or inbuilt addresses which suppose to link to your locaslhost. Usually they work (depending on Android version) but apparently they do not work in your case.