# Can Android device see WCF host?

Tags: java, android, web-services, wcf, android-emulator

I would like to know if an android device can see the WCF host ?

I can't call my WCF service with the localhost (10.0.2.2) adress.

But when I call my WCF in browser I have this :

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">Test done !</string>
```

If it's normal, I think it's the anwser for this question : 
[WCF used in Android Project (FileNotFoundException)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411167/wcf-used-in-android-project-filenotfoundexception)

Comment: If your app can reach your service from an emulator then that app on a real Android device can reach that service too if the Android device is in the same network as the pc with the server.

Comment: Where do you call your WCF in browser and how?

Comment: @greenapps I can't reach my service from my emulator because I have a 'TIMED_OUT' when I call it. I call with this link 'http://localhost:49363/Service1.svc/TestAndroid'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser this you use to call WCF service is simulator browser or PC browser?

If you use simulator by Genymotion then ip address of your WCF service(run on your PC) must be `10.0.3.2`.

Comment: I used both : Web browser is working but my emulator can't reach it. I use Android Studio emulator. I don't know what is Genymotion.

Comment: Ok, your service run on IIS_express?
Show me your network info of simulator?

Comment: Yes my service is running on IIS express

Comment: uhhm, you can follow this post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799134/invalid-hostname-not-able-to-connect-iis-express-from-android-emulator]  or search with keywords ```android emulator access iis express``` or simple turn off your server firewall. Good luck!

Comment: `Web browser is working`. Where ? When How? You know there are more places where browsers can run. You should be very specific.

Comment: @greenapps I turned off the firewall and it didn't work. I used in Chrome, I was in debug mode