# How can Android Emulator reach server on local network?

Tags: android, networking, android-emulator, windows-10

I want to connect to a server on my local network (`10.134.0.178:80`). The ip address of my machine is `10.134.3.12` and the ip address of the emulator Wi-Fi is `192.168.232.2`.

Now I found out that you have to use `10.0.2.2` to connect to a server on your local machine. But the server isn't running on my local machine - instead it is a separate instace on my LAN.

My local machine can reach and ping the server without problems. The emulator not, but the emulator has internet access. So I can access e.g. *www.google.com*.

How can I connect the emulator with the server? The shown [redirection rules](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking) only apply on port level. So how is this meant to be used? Other solutions only talk about a local server. [Only one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51986677/426227) is talking about a similar case, but this is not working for me (no connection)

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=80 connectport=80 connectaddress=10.134.0.178
```

Additionally, I have to switch server instances (different ips/ports/addresses). So how can I use the Android Emulator in this case? To which address should the webservice calls be made? `10.0.2.2` or `10.134.0.178`?

Comment: you need to connect to the same wifi network , use ipconfig to find your pc ip and try to open it in your mobile browser and check

Comment: Why should I do that? I don't have a local webserver or anything like that on my machine. But if I do that I get *This 10.134.3.12 page can't be found* ... I'm also not using WiFi - it's all ethernet. Only the emulator simulates WiFi.

Comment: what type of server do you use ?

Comment: did you configure your server with IIS ?

Comment: There is no IIS involved. There are webservice calls made based on SOAP.

Comment: try to access your profile with the machine ip not the local host

Comment: I don't fully get what you mean, but I tried to access the server ip (= machine ip?) on `10.134.0.178:80` without success. Now I fired up a local webserver and I can browse it in the emulator if I connect to `10.0.2.2`. But that's not what I want, because I need the real server, which isn't running on my local machine. So I can only access localhost (`10.0.2.2`), but no other network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what the reason was, but the most plausible one is, that the server had a temporal issue. Now I can connect to my server without further changes!

One thing what still didn't work for me was `ping`, but it is listed under [*Local networking limitations*](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking#networkinglimitations):

> Depending on the environment, the emulator might not be able to support other protocols (such as ICMP, used for "ping"). Currently, the emulator does not support IGMP or multicast.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, well, your Android app should connect to the server's address/port as it appears to the host machine running the Android emulator. I have a web server on my LAN and my emulator can access it directly. Start with pointing Chrome in your emulator at a web server on your LAN (assuming you have one on there somewhere) - if the server is on 10.134.0.178:80 then just type 10.134.0.178 in to your Chrome address bar. If that's not working then you need to look and see what's stopping it - any redirection rules getting in the way?

Comment: I fired a development environment up and I have now a webserver running on my machine. Within Chrome I can access my local webserver with `10.0.2.2`. But I can't access the real server on `10.134.0.178:80`. As you said the question is why and how do I find that out. Where do I find redirection rules? I deleted the `netsh` command if you meaned that.

Comment: One more question: What is your host ip and what is your webserver ip?

Comment: Are you sure the server is not behind a proxy? https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking
explains how to set up proxy support.

Comment: Nope. Strangely now everything works, but I didn't changed anything. I feel silly right now, because I wasted everyones time. You can read my answer if you would like. I'll delete the question soon ... Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm glad you haven't deleted this question. I ran into the exact same issue. I can reach the internet from the emulator but when I try to resolve to a server within my LAN, I get errors that the host is unreachable. Very frustrating since I need access to that server and it is not on a public IP.